# Excel: How to add logarithmic trendline or curve on a scatter graph when it starts at 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

basically I need to have a graph that looks something like this:

[image]

However using the smooth lines chart type is wonky, and I can't add a logarithmic trendline because the value starts at 0. Is there any easy solution for this? I'm using Excel 2010.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some fairly sophisticated data analysis in Excel using [Solver](https://www.eng.auburn.edu/~clemept/CEANALYSIS_FALL2011/Week1/solverproject1.pdf). But here's a simple trial-and-error method to fit a curve manually.

The equation of the curve you're looking for is of the form `Ao(1-e^(-kx))`.  This is a common equation used to model processes in a variety of areas (chemical kinetics, electronics, etc.)  There are only two constants to adjust, and you can try various values for these and watch the fitted curve change in real time.

Here is a graph of part of your data and the added curve that fits the data:

[image]

And here is the data table including the calculated fitted curve:

[image]

The formula for the fit is: `=D$2*(1-EXP(-E$2*A2))`.  Ao is the value of the function as x approaches infinity, so it's easy to guess it's value as the "plateau" of your data.  The other constant determines how quickly the curve approaches the plateau.  You can adjust the constants and judge the fit by eye.

If you want to get real fancy, you can calculate the "sum of the squares" and adjust the constants to minimize this value.  The sum of squares is the total of the squared differences between each data point and the y-value of the fit for that point.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks! apparently my formula only had beta as a variable so all I had to do was add more points, but this came in handy on another graph of the same type that I had to do with experimental values.